# Adjust vertical alignment of checkmark for obtained badges

Tags: bug, badges, design

This is a view of the badge description and checkmark for a specific badge (say, [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard)):

[image]

Here is the same badge description from the [list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges):

[image]

Could we adjust the vertical alignment of the checkmark in the former display to match that of the second? I suspect adjustments would have to be made for both the checkmark and the badge.

<sub>As a side-note: Why would there be a period at the end of the first display, but not the second?</sub>